# Sort DB entries in a nested SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem I can't get around. With following script I get some duplicates  based on some criteria. I want to sort these depending on 
the date (O.SL_OBJ_LAST_CHANGED_DATE) and get only the oldest one for every source_io

```
select O.sl_obj_id, O.SL_OBJ_LAST_CHANGED_DATE, tm.source_io
from SL_PP01_FAQ01 F,
     SL_PP01_TRANS_META TM,
     SL_PP01_OBJ O,
     (select source_io, lang
      from SL_PP01_TRANS_META M,
           sl_pp01_obj obj
      where lang <> 'de'
        and M.sl_obj_id = obj.sl_obj_id
        and obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
      group by source_io, lang
      having count(M.sl_obj_id) > 1) D
WHERE TM.source_io = D.source_io
  AND TM.lang = D.lang
  AND TM.sl_obj_id = F.sl_obj_id
  AND TM.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id
  and O.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
order by TM.source_io;
```

My output right now:

```
sl_obj_id || sl_obj_last_changed_date || source_io
255018    || 25.01.2017               || 123456
356718    || 23.06.2018               || 123456
467876    || 12.01.2015               || 789012
568631    || 10.08.2014               || 789012
828428    || 10.10.2017               || 135791
424524    || 05.05.2016               || 135791
```

My wished output would be only the older date for each of the source_io's:

```
sl_obj_id || sl_obj_last_changed_date || source_io
255018    || 25.01.2017               || 123456
568631    || 10.08.2014               || 789012
424524    || 05.05.2016               || 135791
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `Row_number` window function to make it.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM (
    SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY source_io ORDER BY sl_obj_last_changed_date ) rn
    FROM youtable t
) t1
where rn = 1
```

This is full code.

I would use `JOIN` instead of `,` connected tables, and you can try to use `CTE` let the code clearer.

```
with CTE AS (
    select O.sl_obj_id, O.SL_OBJ_LAST_CHANGED_DATE, tm.source_io
    from SL_PP01_FAQ01 F 
    JOIN SL_PP01_TRANS_META TM ON TM.sl_obj_id = F.sl_obj_id
    JOIN SL_PP01_OBJ O ON TM.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id
    JOIN (select source_io, lang
          from SL_PP01_TRANS_META M,
               sl_pp01_obj obj
          where lang <> 'de'
            and M.sl_obj_id = obj.sl_obj_id
            and obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
          group by source_io, lang
          having count(M.sl_obj_id) > 1) D ON TM.lang = D.lang
    WHERE TM.source_io = D.source_io
      and O.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
    order by TM.source_io
)

SELECT t1.* FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY source_io ORDER BY sl_obj_last_changed_date ) rn
    FROM CTE t1
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number() function:

```
with cte1 (sl_obj_id, sl_obj_last_changed_date,source_io) as
(
select O.sl_obj_id, O.SL_OBJ_LAST_CHANGED_DATE, tm.source_io
from SL_PP01_FAQ01 F,
     SL_PP01_TRANS_META TM,
     SL_PP01_OBJ O,
     (select source_io, lang
      from SL_PP01_TRANS_META M,
           sl_pp01_obj obj
      where lang <> 'de'
        and M.sl_obj_id = obj.sl_obj_id
        and obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
      group by source_io, lang
      having count(M.sl_obj_id) > 1) D
WHERE TM.source_io = D.source_io
  AND TM.lang = D.lang
  AND TM.sl_obj_id = F.sl_obj_id
  AND TM.sl_obj_id = O.sl_obj_id
  and O.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
order by TM.source_io;
)

select * from 
(
select sl_obj_id, sl_obj_last_changed_date,source_io, row_number() over(partition by source_io order by sl_obj_last_changed_date) as rn from cte1) a where rn=1
```